# docker saved image, how to run?

Tags: docker

I have a testlink docker image running (named 'otechlabs/testlink').

Question 1: How do I get the original url from which I downloaded it (I can't remember) ? I would like to see the instructions about how to run the container.

It's running so fine that I saved a commit of it to run in another machine.

Question 2: Should I remember the run parameters(I can't remember)?

The container was created around 3 months ago.

Question 3: Instead of save/load, should I export/import?

Since I don't remember how to run the image, then I guess I should skip this step, perhaps (someway) copying the image to just start it in another host.

Answer (score 0):

**Q1:**

You can try looking up the image in [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/). The name `otechlabs/testlink` suggests that the user ***otechlabs*** in dockerhub has an image called testlink.

Now, I tried looking up the user's profile [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/otechlabs/) but it appears that he doesn't have anything uploaded yet, maybe it is a private image.

If you're lucky you might be able to find something useful from other people's `testlink` image page.

Example:
https://hub.docker.com/r/rodrigodirk/testlink/

**Q2:**

Not quite sure what you meant here. Well if you have a running container of it, you can always do a `docker inspect [CONTAINER_ID]` to revisit the parameters used for starting it.

Example:

```
  "Config": {
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "5432/tcp": {},
            "9001/tcp": {}
        },
        "Env": [
            "affinity:container==47eea8a078ad47583b4f5343302e7939a6d5f04ad929a079d8d9ae7cbee96d6a",
            "POSTGRES_USER=bigCat01"
        ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Q1: If you did a 'docker pull' the image id contains the url; if the id does not contain a domain name, then it is by default dockerhub repository

Q2:  (as mentioned by Samual) if you still have a container saved run 'docker inspect ' to display the startup param's

Q3: if you modified the container you can 'commmit' the changes, and you can also change the tag: 'docker tag old_tag new_tag'

To help move it around, you could change he tag to gcr.io/project-id/new_tag:version and push it to google's container registry (free 30 day trail, may be free beyond that if you keep resource usage low) in your project 'project-id'